# Place Exit Button On Android Application

Tags: android

I am developing one application. In that application I want to put Exit button.
By clicking Exit Button I want to exit from application.

I used the following code:

> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
>   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
>   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
>   startActivity(intent);
>   finish();

It exit the application but not stop all activities which are running in that application.

Please give me some suggestion to solve this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was discussed many times already. You shouldn't make any "exit" buttons in your application. That's against Android nature and best practices. Look at [Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon) for wider discussion.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
system.exit(0);
```